# Jquery draggable with bootstrap modal, scroller strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use bootstrap modal popup with jquery-ui draggable functionality. 
I use it like this:

```
        // Bootstrap modal
        $(element).modal({ keyboard: false,
                           show: value
        });
        // Jquery draggable
        $(element).draggable({
            handle: ".modal-header"
        });
```

But when I try to drag the popup right scroller is dragging with popup.
Thx for any advance.

Comment: Make fiddle of your problem

Answer (score 36, accepted):

i think you should apply `draggable` on the `.modal-dialog` class, see:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal --> 
</div>

<script>
        $('.modal').modal({ keyboard: false,
                           show: true
        });
        // Jquery draggable
        $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
            handle: ".modal-header"
        });
</script>
```

Comment: @Bass-Jobsen can we also provide keyboard up and down handler to the current modal movement?

Answer (score 0):

Nice answer by @Bass Jobsen

However I felt that sometimes we might need to dynamically resize the modal. So here extending Bass's solution for resizable and draggable modal

Addition

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

and

`$('.modal-content').resizable();`

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal --> 
</div>

<script>
        $('.modal').modal({ keyboard: false,
                           show: true
        });
        // Jquery draggable
        $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
            handle: ".modal-header"
        });
        $('.modal-content').resizable();

</script>
```

Further, you can specify the minHeight and minWidth

```
$('.modal-content').resizable({
    minHeight: 100,
    minWidth: 100
});
```